# Compare two NSDates

Tags: cocoa, compare, nsdate

How can I compare two NSDates and return the amount of time between them.

For example:

```
2010-06-20 14:29:41 -0400
2010-06-20 14:53:29 -0400
```

should return something like: `23` or `24`(minutes), rounding the seconds because I don't really need the seconds.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try something like:

```
int intervall = (int) [date1 timeIntervalSinceDate: date2] / 60;
```

Comment: Note that this may evaluate to a negative number of minutes, depending on which date is earlier. Either negate the number if it is negative, or use the `abs` or `fabs` function.

Answer (score 2):

Here the complete snippet to compare two NSDate which you may find more useful based on your query.

```
NSCalendar *myCal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSString *str =@"12:15, 01 15 2012 AM";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm, dd MM yy a"];

NSDate *refDate = [formatter dateFromString:str];
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];



NSUInteger unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *difference = [myCal components:unitFlags fromDate:refDate     toDate:today options:0];
NSLog(@"%@",difference);
```

------------------------------what you will get is -----------------------------------------

Calendar Year: 0    Month: 0    Day: 0    Hour: 1    Minute: 19